# Why entering a float value in the integer variable is giving me strange answer?

Tags: c

In the following C program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter the values of a and b : ");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    printf("%d %d",a,b);
    return 0;

}
```

If I give the value "3.2," the answer which I am getting is = 3 1
Can someone please explain what is going on ? I am using DEV C++ Compiler.

Comment: Check the result of functions!

Comment: ... and you will find `scanf` is returning `1` instead of the `2` you (??) expect.

Comment: @SagarParashar the reason is because `b` has never been set. My test returns the arbitrary `0`, but if I define `int b=42` then it remains as `42`.

Comment: @WeatherVane - But if I am giving 3.2 2, again the answer is coming 3 1

Comment: Think about the meaning of **undefined**.

Comment: the %d stops inputting when it sees the '.'  A '.' is not white space.  so the next %d cannot skip the '.'.  The result is the second input variable is never set.  In reality, nothing is ever actually consumed from the '.' and onward in the input stream.  So it does not matter what else was typed in by the user

Answer (score 2):

The function `scanf` is trying to read two `int` values. You give it `3.2` and it reads `3` into the `a` , stopping at the `.`.

It then tries to read `.2` into `b` but fails, because `.` is not considered to be `whitespace`.

So `b` is never set and the function returns `1` to show it converted 1 input.

You can show this by initialising `int b=42` and after the `scanf` you'll find that `b` is still `42`.

Comment: @SagarParashar: Instead of commenting that (do not!), you just should upvote a usefull answer. Pleaser take the [tour].

Comment: @Olaf - I have done that already. . . . I just want to let people know that their answers are really helpful to me . . :)